# Angular TypeError: text.replace is not a function. ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to mask all the chars except the last four using a filter in angularjs.
 I am getting the following error.

[image: Error]

HTML :

```
<table>
...
 <tr ng-repeat="emp in FiltredCorpEmployees  | orderBy:propertyName:reverse" ng-model="emp.evaluationStatusId">
    <td class="col-md-2 text-center">{{emp.hashSSN | MaskText}}</td>
</tr>

..
</table>
```

JS :

```
DashBoardModule.filter('MaskText', function () {
    //debugger;
    return function (text) {
        if (!text) {
            return text;
        }
        return text.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'X');
    };
})
```

Comment: `.replace` is only available for strings, what if you `console.log(typeof text)`?

Comment: @jessh thank u. figured out what the issue was .   console.log(typeof text)? returns number.

Comment: give this a try see what comes up : `text.toString().replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'X')`

Comment: @akazemis thank u very much. as this is under comment I am not able to mark it as answer. if u can put the same under answer I will mark it as answer.

Comment: @r mk r , I put it in answers, thanks for your consideration :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give this a try see what comes up :

```
 text.toString().replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'X')
```

Answer (score 0):

convert to string

`<td class="col-md-2 text-center">{{emp.hashSSN.toString() | MaskText}}</td>`